# React passing argument by path with router and does not render properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-props

I have the problem in React, with passing id argument using path in router.
That is my code(index.js):

```
class App extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Home>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/mail/:id" component={Mail} />
                        <Route path="/mail" component={Mail} />
                    </Switch>
                </Home>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}}
```

Next, in Mail.jsx, I have the render function:

```
    render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state;
    return (

        <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={4}>
        <Menu fluid vertical tabular>
    <Menu.Item  name='mail1' active={activeItem === 'mail1'} onClick={this.handleItemClick}> {this.props.match.params.id}</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
</Grid.Column>

    <Grid.Column stretched width={12}>
        <div>
            <Segment>
                {this.state.mails.length > 0 && this.state.mails ? this.state.mails[0].name : null}
            </Segment>
        </div>
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>

    )
}
```

The problem is, that when I write http://localhost:3000/mail I see the "this.state.mails[0].name" and no id ofcourse because I didnt pass one, but when I write http://localhost:3000/mail/5 I can see the number five on the page, but no "this.state.mails[0].name" anymore, why is that?

And getting data from json file:

```
    componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("db.json")
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                mails: response.data.mail,
                total: response.data.mail.length
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

Edit, that is my render function in Home.jsx:

```
 render() {
  const { activeItem } = this.state;

return(
  <div>
    <div>
    <MenuExampleSecondaryPointing/>
    </div>
    <div>
                    {this.props.children}
    </div>
</div>

  );
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding exact path = to the second Route?

Comment: I've tried now, didn't help :/
I've forgot, that is my render function in Home.jsx:
 render() {
      const { activeItem } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
        <div>
        <MenuExampleSecondaryPointing/>
        </div>
        <div>
                        {this.props.children}
        </div>
    </div>

      );
    }

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer from a friend, that is that simple as that:
" axios.get("db.json")" should be "axios.get("/db.json")"
because with "/" I search in all catalogs for that file